# how to add new categorical column in pandas

Tags: pandas, optimization, categorical-data

I have a dataframe like this, with 10M rows:

```
                     probe
time                      
2016-01-01 00:05:00    3
2016-01-01 00:05:00    1
2016-01-01 00:05:00    5
2016-01-01 00:05:00    5
2016-01-01 00:05:00    4
2016-01-01 00:05:00    2
2016-01-01 00:05:00    5
2016-01-01 00:05:00    6
2016-01-01 00:05:00    3
2016-01-01 00:05:00    4
2016-01-01 00:05:00    5
2016-01-01 00:05:00    2
2016-01-01 00:05:00    3
2016-01-01 00:05:00    3
2016-01-01 00:05:00    5
Name: probe, dtype: uint8
```

I want to add a categoricat column based on the value of `probe`

```
def categorize_R(x):
    return "inner" if x['probe'] in (1, 4) else "outer"

data['category_R'] = pandas.Categorical(data.apply(categorize_R, axis=1))
```

this is terribly slow. Actually computing a mask like this:

```
mask_inner = (x['probe'] == 1) | (x['probe'] == 4)
```

is quite fast, but then I don't know how to add a column of type categorical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask created by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
mask = data.probe.between(1,4)
data['category_R']  = pd.Categorical(np.where(mask, 'inner', 'outer'))
print (data)
                     probe category_R
time                                 
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      1      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      4      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      2      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      6      outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      4      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      2      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer
```

Another solution is use [`Categorical.from_codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.from_codes.html), check also [object creation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#object-creation) - `In [28]:`:

```
mask = (data['probe']==1) | (data['probe']==3) | (data['probe']==4)

mask = (data['probe']==1) | (data['probe']==3) | (data['probe']==4)
data['category_R']  = pd.Categorical(np.where(mask, 'inner', 'outer'))
data['category_R1']  = pd.Categorical.from_codes(mask, ['outer','inner'])
print (data)
                     probe category_R category_R1
time                                             
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner       inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      1      inner       inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer       outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer       outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      4      inner       inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      2      outer       outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer       outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      6      outer       outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner       inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      4      inner       inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer       outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      2      outer       outer
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner       inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      3      inner       inner
2016-01-01 00:05:00      5      outer       outer
```

**Timings**:

```
In [181]: %timeit pd.Categorical(np.where(mask, 'inner', 'outer'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 196 µs per loop

In [182]: %timeit pd.Categorical.from_codes(mask, ['outer','inner'])
10000 loops, best of 3: 139 µs per loop
```

Comment: we are close. The point is that I need to do also something more complicated as `(x[probe]==1) | (x[probe]==3) | (x[probe]==4)`

Comment: in addition: it would be nice to avoid the creation of the intermediate series with strings and to create directly the one with categories

Comment: `numpy.where` is very fast and output is numpy array, also you can change mask as you need - check last edit.

Comment: perfect: I am more worried about memory than cpu

Comment: Ya, I like it too ;)